# How can I find out which component does not have a unique key?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I have a very complicated form with lots of components and several lists written with Reagent in Clojurescript and I get warnings like this from time to time

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. 
Check the render method of `views.form.form_content`
```

But I can't find out which component does not have a key. Is there any way to find out which component causes the issue?

Comment: What React version do you use? In old React version it showed without stack information. In `v15.2.0` and higher React has component stack information in key warnings. So you may look at it.

Comment: @TheReason I can see the last method in stack, but there are a lot of components rendered inside this method and I can't find out which one of them causes the issue.

Comment: Search for each loop if the wrapping component you return has a `key` prop, splitting your component can help. We may find it for you if you can show your code.

Comment: @Dyo I know I can do that manually, but I was wondering if there is a more general way to do it/

Comment: You can take a look at this eslint rule if you're using eslint https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md